# Duplicate Answer Same Author

Tags: discussion

How are you supposed to flag answers that are almost the exact same answer from the same author?

I'm leaning towards `in need of moderator intervention`. Although I'm not quite sure it is serious enough to require that level of flagging.

---

For example, these two answers are obviously duplicates by the same author.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993655/894067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993696/894067

Comment: Do you mean duplicate answers to the same question?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes. Same question, almost identical answers. No major differences between the two answers at all. And same author for the answers.

Comment: Do you have a link to one? I've never seen this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes. Not sure if this is the place to share it tho. Don't wanna get into the shame game. But would be happy to share if it would be beneficial.

Comment: I think without at least one example it's hard to come up with advice regarding your question here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Just updated the original post

Comment: A new user who didn't know what they were doing - not something to worry about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Got it. Should it still be flagged tho to ensure it gets addressed?

Comment: It seems both of the linked answers were just deleted by a diamond mod. (I'm not sure why _both_. Admittedly they didn't look particularly great, but at a glance they did seem like valid answers to me.)

Comment: Verbatim copies of someone else's answer already on the question aren't allowed because they add nothing. I don't think the post author being the same changes this. But I'd be hesitant about NAA/VLQ flag if the duplicate answer does look like a genuine answer - I wouldn't bet on queue reviewers recognizing that it's a dupe. Maybe custom mod flag so you can explain?